# Symfony - Exception get message string comparison

Tags: php, symfony, exception, comparison

I have a problem. I'am catching an exception and i want to personalize the error message depending on the exception message.

so I want to check if my excpetion contains a certain string to dislay a specific message.
here is my code :

```
  try {
                    $em->persist($document);
                    $em->flush();
                } catch (\Exception $ex) {

                    $error = "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry";

                    throw new \Exception('Erreur lors de l\'upload du fichier');
                }
```

so i want to do something like

```
if($ex->getMessage() "contain" $error){throw new \Exception....}
```

but don't know how to do it

anyone have an idee ? 
thanks

Comment: You could try the strpos method from php

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to specify exceptions for such cases. So, instead of parsing message string you will catch a special exception like this:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch(NotFoundException) {
}
catch(CustomException) {}
```

etc.

In Symfony you can also define a kernel exception listener (see more details here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and handle your exceptions depending on its type.

Comment: thx I solved my problem but I will take a look to this maybe it will be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

as answered in the comment on my question I solve my problem by using the strpos method